# Expression of type java.lang.string does not conform to expected type String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I get the error `Expression of type java.lang.string does not conform to expected type String`, when I try to compile the following code:

```
case class MyForeachWriterClass[String] extends ForeachWriter {

  var spark: SparkSession
  var param: String
  var mySet: Broadcast[Map[String,String]]
  var myFeatures: Broadcast[Map[String,Array[String]]]
  var producer: KafkaProducer[String,String]
  var logger: Logger

  def this(spark: SparkSession,
           param: String,
           mySet: Broadcast[Map[String,String]],
           myFeatures: Broadcast[Map[String,Array[String]]],
           producer: KafkaProducer[String,String],
           logger: Logger)
  {
    this()
    this.spark = spark
  }

  def process(row: String): Unit =
  {
    logger.info(s"Processing ${row}")

    if (param == "yes") {
      logger.info("Parsing data to JSON.")
      var pid: String = "A"
   }
}
```

The error arises on the line `var pid: String = "A"`. However I do not understand why it does not compile. What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why: `case class MyForeachWriterClass[String]`
This makes `String` a *type-parameter*. So that if you do something like `val x = MyForeachWriterClass[Int]` then every place, where you have `String` will actually be `Int`.

I am not sure what the intent is here, but it looks like you want to just drop the `[String]` part altogether. Or try `class MyForeachWriterClass extends ForeachWriter[String]`.

Also, `case` classes without parameters do not make very much sense.

And also `vars` (and mutable state in general) aren't idiomatic in scala. There is probably a (much) better way to write what you are trying to do ...